# Can I find quadratic function when Im being given x and y values?

Tags: c++, math

I was doing an algorithm where Im given x and y solution, and I need to find if possible, quadratic formula for that solutions.
What I actually mean is:
If Im given output:

```
f(1) = 1 
f(2) = 5
f(3) = 13
f(4) = 25
```

So, the function should return `1,5,13,25`
Function that gives that output is: 2x^2-2x+1, but how do I get that?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you done so far?

Comment: No guarantee that it'd be unique.  Lots of the same equations could have the same roots.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you mean that "I'm given output" and "function should return"? Do you mean that `f(1)=1, f(2)=5, f(3)=13, f(4)=25`? If so, how exactly are those values input to your program? And how should your program output the resulting polynomial--should it look like `2x^2-2x+1` or like `2, -2, 1` or something else? Also, what have you tried so far and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit a parabola to set of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846908/how-to-fit-a-parabola-to-set-of-points)

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I've done it by solving system of linear equations that MBo suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your y-values are precise, you can solve system of linear equations

```
a*x1^2 + b*x1 + c = y1
a*x2^2 + b*x2 + c = y2
a*x3^2 + b*x3 + c = y3
```

substitute known values for three points and find unknowns coefficients a,b,c

If values are approximate, use [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) method (more precise - polynomial least squares) with all points

Comment: Note that this very quickly becomes numerically unstable as the degree of the polynomial you're looking for increases. It should work just fine for a quadratic function though.

Answer (score 0):

This is piece of code for least sqaure analysis. It is written for newmat matrix library. Because i don't use it right now so i am too lazy to rewrite it into armadillo library i am currently using. Just to avoid mistakes newmat starts with vector/matrix indexes from 1 instead of 0.

```
void polynomial_approx( const vector<double>& x, const vector<double>& fx, vector<double>& coeff, int pd)
{
// x - input values of independent variable
//   fx - input values of dependent variable
//   coeff - output vector with polynomial coeffiecients
    //   pd - polynomial degree

    if ( x.size() < pd ){
        cerr << "Not enough data for such high polynomial degree." << endl;
    };
    coeff.clear();

    Matrix A(x.size(), pd + 1);
    Matrix D(pd+1,pd+1);
    ColumnVector y(fx.size());
    ColumnVector dx;

    // converting vector from c++ type to newmat vector
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < fx.size(); i++)
        y(i+1) = fx[i];

    // creating the design matrix
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= x.size();i++ ){
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j<= pd+1;j++ ){
            A(i,j) = pow(x[i],j-1);
        }
    }
    // compute the unknown coefficients
    dx = (A.t() * A ).i() * A.t() * y;

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i<= dx.Ncols(); i++)
        coeff.push_back( dx(i) );

    /* reconstruction of polynomial */
    vector<double> recon (x.size(), 0.0 );
    for (  unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size() ; i++){
        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j< coeff.size(); j++){
            recon[i] += coeff[j]*pow( x[i], (double) j  );
        }
    }
}
```