# How to get connect two part of curve and get the points position of connecting curve?

Tags: c++, opencv, curve-fitting, bezier

I have two parts of curve. The points position(x,y) of curve have been known. How to connect them and get the position of the connecting curve?Here is a  similar question.[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805956/how-can-i-fit-points-to-curve-using-c)
He said to use Bezier curves. But in my opinion,usually, the fitting curve not pass through the control points. So if i select some points from two parts of curve as control points, the fitting result may be as following picture. That is not my goal.Can somebody give me some advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then use the alternative proposed solution which is Splines :) because the curve pass from the points

Comment: or Catmull-Rom curves, which also go through points, and are trivially rewritten to cubic Bezier form. This question is pretty much literally what they were invented for =)

Answer (score 4):

Use a Catmull-Rom curve, which is related to Bezier curves and easy to convert into Bezier form, with the benefit that is goes "through" points, instead of merely being controlled by them. For the fine details see http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv, but we basically need those two end points, and two points outside of the curve that ensure we have the correct tangent at our two on-curve points:

[image]

p2 and p3 are "your" points, and p1 and p4 are somewhat arbitrary: we just need to make sure that the line `p1--p3` is parallel to the tangent at p2 (tangent and its parallel line indicated in bluish purple), and similarly that the line `p2--p4` is parallel to the tangent at p3 (tangent and its parallel line indicated in pinkish). A generally easy approach is to just [project points p2 and p3 onto the parallel lines](http://www.vcskicks.com/code-snippet/point-projection.php).

As long as we make sure that's true, we can form the connecting segment as a Catmull-Rom segment with curve coordinates (p1,p2,p3,p4). If there is no Catmull-Rom drawing primitive, though, we can trivially draw it as a Bezier curve, by using the following cubic Bezier curve coordinates:

1. start point: p2
2. control point 1: p2 + (p3-p1)/(6*t)
3. control point 2: p3 - (p4-p2)/(6*t)
4. end point: p3

The `t` value here is the tension of the Catmull-Rom curve; the higher you make this, the "tighter" the join looks (with the default tension in most graphic contexts that support Catmull-Rom simply being 1).

Some example values:

[image]

Note that in each example the tangent direction at points p2 and p3 are preserved, but the *length* of the tangent vector is different, leading to very tight, to nice, to way too loose fittings.

Comment: Can i ask two more question? 1.Why are start/end points p1,p4 on  parallel line? Can i use the points on the curve as start/end and control points, because i know all the points position on the curve.  2.I have found Equation 2 here http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/, but i want to use more control points to make it more accurate. Can you show me the General Equation, for example, i want to use 10 control points

Comment: 1: already explained in the answer and the link given (you need to preserve the tangent at points p2, controlled by line p1--p3, and p3, controlled by line p2--p4). 2: no, you don't. You don't make Catmull-Rom curves "more accurate" by adding "more control points".

Comment: Thank you very much.1.But i cannot find the explanation about  why i need to preserve the tangent at points p2, controlled by line p1--p3,also p3. 2.You mean that Catmull-Rom curves just can use one or two control point?Sorry about too many question.

Comment: if you want a smooth connecting segment, you need to preserve the *direction* of the curve through P2 and P3. Otherwise you get kinks. tangents for on-curve points in Catmull-Rom curves always run parallel to the line from the point preceding it to the point next to it, and so you need to match the location of P1 and P3 to that. You already have P3, so we need to place P1 such that the line p1--p3 is parallel to the tangent at p2. (and the same for P3 with points p2 and p4). See http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv

Answer (score 0):

As I commented Splines could be a better solution than Bezier in this case. However, you may also use a more simple one. you have 4 points (red). Try to fit them in Polynomial (3rd degree since you have just 4) using this formula:

```
A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D = y
```

You have 4 Points (`P0,P1,P2,P3`):

```
A x0^3 + B x0^2 + C x0 + D = y0
A x1^3 + B x1^2 + C x1 + D = y1
A x2^3 + B x2^2 + C x2 + D = y2
A x3^3 + B x3^2 + C x3 + D = y3
```

Solving this system of linear equation will give you the values of `A,B,C,D`.

To get the part of the curve that is missing:

```
for(auto x=P1.x; x<P2.x; ++x){
    auto y=A*x*x*x + B*x*x + C*x + D;
    cv::circle(image,cv::Point(x,y),.......);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.But i think express curve as y=A x^3 + B x^2 + C x + D is not very good because the shape is rotated. http://www.mathopenref.com/cubicexplorer.html

Comment: You showed that you have just 4 points so no other option is avaible.. do you have more?

Comment: @All points position on the curve have been known. We can use every point. I just selected four from them

Comment: Then you can increase the degree of the polynomial to 4 or 5 or what ever, since you have another points to add them to the equations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rule out Bezier curves. You're correct that the curve often doesn't intersect the control points, but the endpoints do and you can use this to constrain the form of the curve.

To be more specific, you can join the lines by constructing a new quadratic Bezier curve - use the endpoints of your two lines as the endpoints of the curve, with the midpoint being the intersection of two imaginary straight line segments extended from the ends of the current line.

[image: Bezier]

In the above example, the red circles are the fixed endpoints of the curve, the green lines are the extended lines, the blue circle is their intersection point (used as the control point), and the blue line is the approximate curve you'll end up with.

**Edit:** After thinking about this a bit more, you probably want to use a cubic curve, and have two blue control points, one on each green line. Positioning each one *L/2* distance away from the endpoints, where *L* is the straight-line distance between the red endpoints, would probably yield good results.  The problem with a quadratic curve is that as the green lines approach parallel, the quadratic curve will end up with a sharp corner near the control point. At parallel, they don't actually intersect at all.  Using a cubic curve will produce a much rounder line, and doesn't have any issue with parallel tangents.  For example, in the image below, the top curve uses quadratic (one control point) and the bottom one uses cubic (two control points).

[image: Bezier2]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you show me mo details about how to get the extended lines?

Comment: @kookoo121 It depends on how your original lines are defined, but assuming they're defined parametrically, you should be able to deduce the tangent vectors at the endpoints then use a normal [line-line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) equation.  For example, if your two original lines were their own Bezier curves, the vector from the last control point to the endpoint is the tangent vector.

Comment: Thank you very much.I will try it